# InvalidOperationException was unhandled - data grid view issue

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, datagridview, xampp

Error: The commandtext property has no been properly initialised.

I have created a data grid view in one of my forms and I am trying to use it to display my database details from xampp. Although when I go to try open the form I get the error above and it directs me to my procedures and variables module to this section:

```
   'Procedure which executes any SQL query.
Public Sub SQL_executer()
    Call connection_checker()

    objdataadapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand()
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objconnection
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = sqlstring

    objcommandbuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(objdataadapter)
    objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset) ----------- THIS SECTION GIVES ERROR
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

End Sub

'Procedure used to load data from the database for the selected table.
Public Sub initial_load()
    Call connection_checker()
    Call SQL_executer()

    objdataset = New DataSet
    objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset, tablename)
    objconnection.Close()

End Sub
```

**This is the relevant code from the form which has the data grid view:**

```
Imports MySql.Data
```

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Drawing.Printing
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class frmClientDetails
    Dim form_type As Form
    Dim user_table As String
    Dim objconnection As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;database=ba-solutions;user id=root;password=")
    Dim sqlstring As String

```
Private Sub frmClientDetails_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    sqlstring = "SELECT * FROM `BA-Solutions`"
    tablename = "`Client_Details`"

    Call initial_load()
    Call bind_dataset_DGVClient()
    Call count_records()
    rowposition = 0

    DGVClient.DataSource = objdataset
    DGVClient.DataMember = tablename
End Sub
```

**And this is my whole procedures and variables module for reference**

```
Imports MySql.Data
```

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Module procedures_and_variables

```
Public objconnection As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;database=ba-solutions;user id=root;password=")

Public objdataadapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Public objdataset As New DataSet
Public objcommandbuilder As New MySqlCommandBuilder
Public objdatatable As New DataTable
Public rowposition As Integer = 0
Public sqlstring As String
Public tablename As String
Public objcommand As MySqlCommand
Public reader As MySqlDataReader
Public database_path As String = "Server=localhost;database=ba-solutions;user id=root;password="
Public path As String
Public backup As New MySqlBackup

'Procedure which checks whether or not the current connection is open and opens it, if it is closed.
Public Sub connection_checker()
    If objconnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        Try
            objconnection.Open()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox("Error connecting to database")
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

'Procedure which executes any SQL query.
Public Sub SQL_executer()
    Call connection_checker()

    objdataadapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand()
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objconnection
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = sqlstring

    objcommandbuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(objdataadapter)
    objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset)
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

End Sub

'Procedure used to load data from the database for the selected table.
Public Sub initial_load()
    Call connection_checker()
    Call SQL_executer()

    objdataset = New DataSet
    objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset, tablename)
    objconnection.Close()

End Sub

'Procedure used to update data in a table with the changes made to the data in the datagrid.
Public Sub update_data()
    Call connection_checker()
    Try
        objdataadapter.Update(objdataset, tablename)
        MsgBox("Changes accepted", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Update successfull")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Changes declined", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Update unsuccessfull")
    End Try
End Sub

'Procedures used to bind the relevant data to the data grid, with the correct header titles.
Public Sub bind_dataset_DGVClient()
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.DataSource = objdataset
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.DataMember = tablename

    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(0).HeaderText = "Company Name"
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Company Type"
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(2).HeaderText = "VAT Registration Number"
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(3).HeaderText = "PAYE and Tax Reference"
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Address Line 1"
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(5).HeaderText = "City"
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(6).HeaderText = "Postcode"
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(7).HeaderText = "Email"
    frmClientDetails.DGVClient.Columns(8).HeaderText = "Phone Number"






    'NEEDS TO BE COMPLETED FOR ALL DATASETS
End Sub
```

End Module

I am new to vb/sql and been working on fixing this for hours with no avail, I'm sure it's pretty simple, but then again I am in no way even a basic expert. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText hasn't been set. The CommandText and the CommandType need to be set before the Fill method is called.

```
objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select statement goes here"
objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset)
```

Comment: Where exactly would I place everything, because I can't use Select statement on databases and if I used it on a table in my module then it would keep calling the same table?

Comment: It would go in SQL_executer.  Are you trying to build a generic method to do all your execute statements ?  I recommend against that, it isn't that much work to setup a command object and fill it.

Comment: I think the first issue is solved but now at this line in my module: frmClientDetails.DGVClient.DataMember = tablename

I get error: Argument exception was unhandled....Child list for field Client_Details cannot be created.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a Select on a DB, you use it on the Table. You can make this more generic by having a variable that you can set to diff tables names and this sql string will load whichever table to tell it to.

```
Public Function ReloadNewTable(tablename As String) As DataTable
  Dim sqlstring = String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tablename)
  'fill a datatable with new query and return the datatable.
```

Your `Connections String` tells it what Db to use. Do not surround table names with the ` char either. Then set the CommandText with this corrected sql string.

Comment: I am still getting the same error, excuse my ignorance, but where do I put everything, I am confused. I don't want to put the select statement in the procedures and variables module, because I will be using the Select statement again for different tables.

Comment: @Livaren, I updated the example so you can use a variable to change the table name.